# Gnome 2 apps do not use system theme (ubuntu mini iso + ubuntu gnome)

Tags: themes

I used Ubuntu mini ISO and installed Ubuntu gnome desktop. Gnome 2 applications like Firefox (and also QT apps) do not use the system theme (Adwaita) and looks ugly.

1) Installed Murrine gnome 2 theme engine

2) Installed `libgnome2-common`

3) Change setting in `qt4-qtconfig` (The `gtk+` theme in `qtconfig` preview looks ugly as well).

Comment: This looks like a question *and* an answer.  Is that so?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, The issue was gtk2-engines-pixbuf was not installed. Once it is installed, everything is working fine again.